# How to add custom text to a bar-plot dependant on y-axis values in R?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have the following barplot that I wish to produce text labels for all horizontal bars that have 4 or more plant species. The colours represent plant families, and therefore i would wish for the text labels to display the names of these (5 or so) plant families (as it is very obvious that displaying a legend for 40+ families of plants would be pure chaos). I can manually enter the family names, but they need to correspond to the correct horizontal bars. Does anyone know how I might do this?

Here is the code for my plot:

```
bp2<-barplot(Table2, xlab=c("Fruit Type"), ylab=c("Number of Plant Species"), col=rainbow(45), ylim=c(0,10), beside=T)
```

I know putting text labels is something like:

```
text(bp2, Table2, labels=Table2, pos=3)
```

But obviously not correct for the task I wish to accomplish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a "good enough" way of solving my problem. The code is:

```
text(X, Y, "Custom Label")
text(X, Y, "Another Custom Label")
```

etc.

Just need to know the x,y coordinates of the horizontal bar that you wish to give a custom label to. Simple code is simple!

EDIT: Final code I used and final product:

```
bp2<-barplot(Table2, xlab=c("Fruit Type"), ylab=c("Number of Plant Species"), col=rainbow(45), ylim=c(0,10), beside=T)
text(20, 9, "Clusiaceae", pos=3)
text(30, 8, "Lauraceae", pos=3)
text(55, 7.5, "Rubiaceae", pos=3)
text(65, 4, "Fabaceae", pos=3)
text(120, 4, "Moraceae", pos=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better if you could provide a reproducible example. 
For example:

```
a<- data.frame(iris[,2])
row.names(a) <- paste("species-", 1:150, sep= "")
```

Now you can choose which row.names to display:

```
barplot(a[,1], names.arg=ifelse(a[,1] > 4, row.names(a), NA) , las =3)
```

That will only display names for which the value of `a` is greater than 4.